# Gnuplot scripting set terminal gives me ascii characters

Tags: gnuplot

I am trying to run gnuplot script in xubuntu that had worked last months but from today it gives me ascii characters and not the desired png file with plot. I track the problem and seems that is at set terminal command.
Any idea?

```
#!/usr/bin/gnuplot 

reset 
set terminal png size 1024,768 

set xlabel "Time" 
set ylabel "Position" 
set title "Title1" 
set key reverse Left outside 
set grid 
set style data lines 

plot "file.txt" using 1:2 title "North", \ 
     "" using 1:3 title "East", \ 
     "" using 1:4 title "Up" #
```

Comment: Can you provide the script? It might also be work asking over on AskUbuntu or Unix&Linux StackExchanges

Answer (score 1):

Finally found a solution,

worked only gif file so i `sudo apt-get purge gnuplot*` and reinstall `sudo apt-get install libgd2-noxpm-dev` then reinstall `sudo apt-get install gnuplot-x11` and everything works!!!!!